# Declaration is incompatible with

Tags: c++

I have an issue compiling and running the code on visual studios. It gives me the error code "declaration is incompatible with" so and so. More specifically, when calling on the header in the code in the beginning of each function from the main CPP. I've tried changing the void to int in the header, but it didn't seem to fix it. I'm stuck now and need some guidance.

The error is:
"Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0147   declaration is incompatible with "void convertTime::invalidHr(int hour)" (declared at line 9 of "Time.h")   Source.cpp  6   "

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Time.h"

using namespace std;

int convertTime::invalidHr(int hour) *//error on this line*
{
int convertHour = hour;

try 
{
    if (hour < 13 && hour > 0)
    {
        hour = hour + 12;
        return hour;
    }
    else {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore();
        cout << "Invalid input! Please input hour again in correct 12 hour format: ";
        cin >> hour;
        invalidHr(hour);
        throw 10;
    }
}
catch (int c) { cout << "Invalid hour input"; }
}

int convertTime::invalidMin(int min) *//error here*
{
int convertMin = min;

try 
{
    if (min < 60 && min > 0)
    {
        return min;
    }
    else {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore();
        cout << "Invalid input! Please input minutes again in correct 12 hour format: ";
        cin >> min;
        invalidMin(min);
        throw 20;
        return 0;
    }
}
catch (int e) { cout << "Invalid minute input" << endl; }
 }

int convertTime::invalidSec(int sec) *//error here*
{
int convertSec = sec;

try 
{
    if (sec < 60 && sec > 0)
    {
        return sec;
    }
    else {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore();
        cout << "Invalid input! Please input seconds again in correct 12 hour format: ";
        cin >> sec;
        invalidSec(sec);
        throw 30;
        return 0;
    }
}
catch (int t) { cout << "Invalid second input" << endl; }
}

void convertTime::printMilTime()
{
cout << "Converted time: " << hour << ":" << min << ":" << sec;
}
```

And here is my header:

```
class convertTime
{
 public:
int hour, min, sec;

void invalidHr(int hour);
void invalidMin(int min);
void invalidSec(int sec);
void printMilTime();
};
```

Comment: Can you show the full error message?

Comment: "_It gives me the error code "declaration is incompatible with" so and so._" Please copy paste the entire error message, without paraphrasing. Since you cut-off the part of the error, that you could tell you (and us), what is wrong.

Comment: "I've tried changing the void to int in the header, but it didn't seem to fix it." - I find it hard to believe. Albeit it appears that you should rather change `int` to `void` in `.cpp` file. Why are you declaring these functions as returning `int` if you are not even trying to actually return anything from them?

Comment: In Visual Studio its best to copy the error message from the Output Tab since it is in a better format than the Errors List. It's also guaranteed to be in file order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return types of the member functions don't match.

In the class definition, you have:

```
void invalidHr(int hour);
void invalidMin(int min);
void invalidSec(int sec);
```

In the implementations, you have:

```
int convertTime::invalidHr(int hour) { ... }
int convertTime::invalidMin(int min) { ... }
int convertTime::invalidSec(int sec) { ... }
```

You need to change one of them so they match.

Comment: Okay, I've changed the header file to int. It now gives compiles and runs, but gives me incorrect numbers no matter what I put in.

Comment: @Lonk Visual Studio has a very good debugger that will let you step through your code a line at a time looking at your variables at each step. When you single step and the code does not do what you expect ask a brand new question if you need help. This question was about the compiler error and it is answered.